# Test::Mojo post_ok not reading in POST data correctly

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am creating a simple Mojolicious app that is to be a REST API for some objects in my database. I am trying to test creating a new object, but POSTing data to the object collection. Here is the basic structure of my Test::Mojo script:

```
use Mojo::Base -strict;
use Test::More;
use Test::Mojo;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ip_node = {ipname => 'ip_alias.subdomain.company.com', ipservice => 'reserved', ipaddress => '192.168.0.1'};

my $t = Test::Mojo->new('Tools');
$t->post_ok('/tools/ipadmin/nodes' => {Accept => 'application/json'} => form => $ip_node)->status_is(201);

done_testing();
```

But for whatever reason, the Mojo Controller cannot read in the POST data when sent in the above fashion. To debug this, in my Controller I have the following lines to respond to the request:

```
my $c = shift;

print "All params: " . $c->req->params . "\n";
print "IP Name: " . $c->req->param("ipname") . "\n";
print "IP Service: " . $c->req->param("ipservice") . "\n";
print "IP Address: " . $c->req->param("ipaddress") . "\n";
```

When I run the test script via prove:

```
$ prove -v -I /path/to/workspace/Tools/lib t/basic.t
```

The output varies between one of these three outputs. Most of the time the all 4 print statements are empty, but occasionally a CRLF + the POST data (with the final two characters stripped off, probably from the CRLF eating up the content_length) and even more rarely the content_length of the HTTP Headers gets output.

```
All params: %0D%0Aipaddress=192.168.0.1&ipname=ip_alias.subdomain.company.com&ipservice=reserv
IP Name: ip_alias.subdomain.company.com
IP Service: reserv
IP Address: 

All params: User-Agent%3A+Mojolicious+%28Perl%29%0D%0AHost%3A+127.0.0.1%3A35611%0D%0AAccept-Encoding%3A+gzip%0D%0A=
IP Name: 
IP Service: 
IP Address: 

All params: 
IP Name: 
IP Service: 
IP Address:
```

Has anyone seen this type of behaviour before? Is something with my post_ok syntax wrong? I've read the Mojo docs for Test::Mojo and it looks (to me) like this should work, but it just doesn't. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `$basic_ip_node`? You initialize `$ip_node` but your post data comes from `$basic_ip_node`.

Comment: Ugh - that's a typo I made while stripping out the unnecessary info. What we initialize is what we pass into the POST data. I've edited the question the have the correct variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this behavior is the result of a stray newline character on my cookie that is passed in to the Controller. I was creating and attaching a Cookie Jar for authn/authz onto the mojo object with:

```
my $jar = Mojo::UserAgent::CookieJar->new;

$jar->add(
    Mojo::Cookie::Response->new(
        name   => "$mojo_cookie_name",
        value  => "$cookie_data",
        domain => "127.0.0.1",
        path   => "$mojo_cookie_path"
    )
);

$t->{ua}->{cookie_jar} =  $jar;
```

But $cookie_data had an extra newline character on it. By performing a chomp() on the $cookie_data before adding it on to the Cookie Jar, everything works as expected. I don't know why the Mojo request failed so spectacularly when there is an extra new line character on the cookie - and I assume it would fail if any manual header has an extra new line character on it as well. If anything further comes of this, I'll updated/comment on this answer accordingly.